# render React component from a string

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, browser, babeljs

I have some React code in the string, for example:

```
const component = `
function App() {
  return (
    <div>
    test
    </div>
  );
}
`;
```

And I want to be able to render that component from within browser, something like:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { render } from 'react-dom';
import * as babel from 'babel-standalone';


const babelCode = babel.transform(component, { presets: ['react', 'es2015'] }).code;

render(eval(babelCode), document.getElementById('WorkFlow'));
```

This particular example doesn't work but it shows what I'm looking for, any help appreciated!

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Babel produces the code with `"use strict"` and `eval()` doesn't work with it well. First, we should remove that line manually.

```
const code = babelCode.replace('"use strict";', "").trim();
```

Ideally, after this following lines should work.

```
eval(code);
render(<App/>, document.getElementById('WorkFlow'));
```

*Note that you don't need to put `eval()` inside render. It doesn't return your App function or anything. Instead, it will add App to context and we can use it after `eval()` statement.*

But usually, React app has a compile step with `webpack` or similar tool and will complain about undefined `App`.

As a workaround, we can wrap our component with a [Function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function) which returns our component itself. Now we can call this function to get our component. But the context of wrapping function doesn't have `React` variable. So we have to pass it manually as a parameter. If you are going to use any other variable from the current context, you will have to pass those as well.

```
const code = babelCode.replace('"use strict";', "").trim();
const func = new Function("React", `return ${code}`);
const App = func(React)
render(<App/>, document.getElementById('WorkFlow'));
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: only one thing, actually it works as it is, but we should enter `new` before `Function` class

Answer (score 1):

React will allow you to render either a `Component` or an `Element`. You can think of an `Element` as a raw HTML code in JSX, while a `Component` is a prototype, which inherits from `React.Component`. In your code you are trying to render a result of evaluating the babel transpiled code, which will fail (I'm not sure what it is, but it's probably `undefined` or `null`). If you want to make it work, first evaluate the code and then invoke the function to pass the `Element` code to the `render` function:

```
eval(babelCode);  // now the App function has been defined and you can use it in the code
render(App(), document.getElementById('WorkFlow'));
       // ^^ here the App function is being invoked
```

---

Old answer (I thought you were trying to pass the `component` as a file not and not as a variable to transpiler):

`babel` will never transpile strings, so this is not going to work out for you. You can however consider using a raw `JS` code instead of `JSX` as your string content. More about it you can read here: https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-without-jsx.html

Comment: why it won't transpile if it does even in example above? I can transform string using babel on client side, question is is it any way to render it after?

Comment: Hey, I misunderstood the concept, I thought you were passing the `component` as a file not and not as a variable to transpiler. Let me edit my answer