# How to generate react components at run time

Tags: reactjs

I am working on an application that gets the html and data from server for ex: `html=<div>{this.state.name}</div> data=name:'john'`

I need to generate the react component using that html and bind the data to the html/component at run time. I know this is not the best way to do things but I do not have any control on it, all the logic is on the server and it drives the UI.

I am able to make it work in angular using `compileModuleAndAllComponentsSync`, basically i define a component give it a template, compile the module and set the data on the component.

I do not know how I can do this in react, I tried `dangerouslySetInnerHTML` but that does not bind the data.

Comment: There are several packages that do this like https://github.com/utatti/react-render-html . It may take additional efforts to make them work with components instead of HTML. See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45645424/render-html-string-in-isomorphic-react-app

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can do something with the `eval()` function? This looks like a similar problem with a solution: [render React component from a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44221026/render-react-component-from-a-string)